# Instead /bin/bash as a shell, /bin/passwd in /etc/passwd file

Tags: unix, shell, login, passwd, etcpasswd

I'm a Unix support Admin and I have a rare situation here.
I have a recently adopted an environment that has a user with a `/bin/passwd` binary as a shell.

```
xxx:x:1:100:xx:/home/xx:/bin/passwd
```

Anyone have a clue about what is this for? Does this have a specific and special function?

Comment: What particular "UNIX" is this? Are you running the original AT&T UNIX System V from the 1980s or something? Or are you just afraid to type "GNU/Linux", "FreeBSD", "Solaris", or whatever your `/etc/issue` file or `uname -a` command tells you? Without knowing the system in particular, it's impossible to provide specific details.

Comment: Wild guess: You run SSH or some other service that can do more than opening interactive sessions (like SCP or port forwarding). Allowing just /bin/passwd will allow the user to change his password, but (hopefully) nothing else interactively (depending on the capabilities of SSH or whatever). configuring /bin/r(ba)sh would be a bit more work.

Answer (score 3):

I know this scenario from my old mail provider. To get the mails you could use POP or IMAP, but there was no web interface. In order to change your passwort, you simply ssh'd into the mail server, and you'll get prompted to change your password. After that you are logged out:

```
Changing password for fooman.
Old Password: 
New Password: 
Bad password: too simple
New Password: 
Reenter New Password: 
Password changed.
Connection to mailserver closed.
```

Achieved:

- easy password change (without web interface)
- customer doesn't get a shell on the mail server

However, I don't know how common this setup is nowadays.